# webdrvierIO file uploading is failing in saucelab

Tags: file-upload, webdriver-io, saucelabs

WebdrvierIO file uploading is failing ,

code:

```
const testFilePath = 'C:/Users/num/Downloads/name-src-ips-work-manager-IPSEsignScenarios/name-src-ips-work-manager-IPSEsignScenarios/test/support/data/ClientGeneralAccountAgreement.pdf';
        //const testFilePath = `../support/data/ClientGeneralAccountAgreement.pdf`;
        const fileUpload = $('.form-upload-textbox');
        browser.execute(
            // assign style to elem in the browser
            (el) => el.style.display = 'block',
            // pass in element so we don't need to query it again in the browser
            fileUpload
        );
        fileUpload.waitForDisplayed();

        //const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'path/to/your/file');
        fileUpload.setValue(testFilePath);

    browser.pause(8000);
```

Error logs:

> script is working in local execution whereas failing in sauce lab 
>   [chrome 79.0.3945.79 Windows #0-0] invalid argument: File not found : ./test/support/data/BestInterestAdviceModel.pdf
>     (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.79)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=79.0.3945.36 (3582db32b33893869b8c1339e8f4d9ed1816f143-refs/branch-heads/3945@{#614}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10586 x86_64)
>   [chrome 79.0.3945.79 Windows #0-0] Error: invalid argument: File not found : ./test/support/data/BestInterestAdviceModel.pdf
>   [chrome 79.0.3945.79 Windows #0-0]   (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.79)
>   [chrome 79.0.3945.79 Windows #0-0]   (Driver info: chromedriver=79.0.3945.36 (3582db32b33893869b8c1339e8f4d9ed1816f143-refs/branch-heads/3945@{#614}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10586 x86_64)
>   [chrome 79.0.3945.79 Windows #0-0]     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
>   [chrome 79.0.3945.79 Windows #0-0]     at 
>   [chrome 79.0.3945.79 Windows #0-0]     at documentUpload (/builds/test-engineering/testing-projects/testing-src/name-src-ips-work-manager/test/support/utils/index.js:78:14)
>   [chrome 79.0.3945.79 Windows #0-0]     at some (/builds/test-engineering/testing-projects/testing-src/name-src-ips-work-manager/test/support/pages/wizardPage.js:54:9)
>   [chrome 79.0.3945.79 Windows #0-0]     at Array.some ()
>   [chrome 79.0.3945.79 Windows #0-0]     at WizardPage.selectAndUploadForm (/builds/test-engineering/testing-projects/testing-src/name-src-ips-work-manager/test/support/pages/wizardPage.js:52:16)
>   [chrome 79.0.3945.79 Windows #0-0]     at World. (/builds/test-engineering/testing-projects/testing-src/name-src-ips-work-manager/test/support/step_definitions/common.js:17:20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't upload files in the cloud (doesn't matter if it's Sauce Labs or a different cloud vendor) like you are used to do on your local machine. The cloud VM doesn't have access to your local file system.

There are 2 possible solutions for Sauce Labs in combination with WebdriverIO.

1. **Chrome only:** There is a Chrome only solution with `browser.uploadFile(localPath)`
2. **Pre-run executable:** With Sauce Labs you can use a pre-run executable to upload a file to a VM and then use that file to upload
   in your application.

You can check them here https://github.com/saucelabs-sample-test-frameworks/WebdriverIO-download-upload

> **NOTE:**
>   You should wonder if testing uploading a file is really something you need to do through the frontend. UI tests tend to be flaky and testing file uploads make them even more flaky.

Comment: Thank you . above approach helped